# How to trigger a hydra when entering evil-mode normal state?

Tags: evil, hooks, hydra

I have the following:

```
(use-package evil
  :hook
  (after-init . evil-mode)
  (evil-normal-state-entry . hydra-evil/body))
```

When leaving the emacs state (with <kbd>C-z</kbd>) and entering normal state, all my buffers are killed and the `*Messages*` buffer reads:

```
walk-window-tree-1: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’
```

Here is the backtrace if relevant: http://ix.io/2sI9

Comment: It would help if you'd state why your use-package code doesn't solve the problem. I've tried writing the equivalent without use-package and ran into bizarre errors. Knowing that much helps tremendously to figure out how to answer this question.

Comment: @wasamasa Looks like the end of my post didn't get through, added the error encountered.

Comment: Both the error message and the backtrace indicate an "infinite" recursion. Beyond that, you got to debug :-)

Comment: @NickD But why would the hook run more than once?

Comment: There is some unexpected interaction: `evil-initialize`  runs tte `evil-normal-state-hook` which calls into hydra, which tries to leave a hint in the `lv` window. That somehow invokes `fundamental-mode` which runs the `after-change-major-mode-hook` which calls `evil-mode-enable-in-buffers` which calls `evil-initialize` and the whole thing repeats. You've got to break the cycle somewhere, but I know nothing about `evil` and almost nothing about `hydra`, so I won't be able to help.